# How can I get skrollr.js to "snap" to certain vertical locations?

Tags: jquery, parallax, skrollr, fullpage.js

I'm using [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) in an attempt to create a [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)-like effect plus parallax.

The issue is that when I skroll --er, scroll through each "slide" of content, sometimes the scroll interval is offset by an amount that makes it impossible to align the top of each section with the top of the viewport, which looks less polished than I'd like.

I'd love to be able to disable scrolling through each section and have it just advance through each slide when the user scrolls faster than a certain mousewheel threshold (eg, not just on one tick), but after pursuing that for awhile, I haven't gotten very far.

Would anyone like to enlighten me on how to do that with Skrollr (or suggest a different jQuery plugin, if it's too difficult to achieve with Skrollr)?

(So far I've tried having it `animateTo()` the next slide when the window-top is aligned with the top of a slide, but apparently the fact that sometimes it doesn't line up perfectly throws that off. Also, I have yet to find a way to disable [even if only temporarily] the normal scroll-through behavior. [It has occurred to me that I may be countered by Skrollr itself while trying to figure this out.])

Comment: "I have yet to find a way to disable [even if only temporarily] the normal scroll-through behavior" apply `overflow:hidden` temporarily